# How to animate diagonal lines growing without rotation in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an animation where I want diagonal lines to grow from their initial height of 0% to 100%, without any rotation. Currently, I have the following CSS code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="stripes-1">
         <span class="rec-1"></span>
         <span class="rec-1"></span>
         <span class="rec-1"></span>
         <span class="rec-1"></span>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.who-we-are {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.stripes-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rec-1 {
  transform: scaleX(100%) rotate(40deg);
  animation: expandHeight 1s ease-in-out forwards;
  width: 72.5%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  animation: appearUp 1.5s linear;
  transition: ease-in ;
  position: relative;
  left: 500px;
  top: 350px;
}

@keyframes appearUp{
  0%{
    transform:scaleX(0) rotate(0deg);
  } 
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(100%) rotate(40deg);
  } 
    
    
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(1){
  border-bottom: 30px solid #1DCDFE;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #11FFC4;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(3) {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #21D0B2;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(4) {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #2F455C;
}
```

The issue is that the lines not only grow but also rotate during the animation. However, I want them to maintain their initial angle of 40 degrees and grow vertically. I've tried adjusting the transform-origin property and adding separate animations, but I couldn't achieve the desired result.

Could someone please guide me on how to modify the CSS animation to make the lines grow from the initial angle of 40 degrees without rotation?

Updated HTML and CSS

Comment: can you send all code  ? where is html

Answer (score 1):

This `transform: scaleX(100%) rotate(40deg);` and this `transform: rotate(40deg) scaleX(100%);` - it is not the same thing.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: end;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.rec-1 {
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  animation: appearUp 1.5s linear both;
  transform: rotate(40deg) scaleX(0);
}

@keyframes appearUp {
  to {
    transform: rotate(40deg) scaleX(100%);
  }
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #1DCDFE;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #11FFC4;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #21D0B2;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #2F455C;
}
```

```html
<div class="rec-1"></div>
<div class="rec-1"></div>
<div class="rec-1"></div>
<div class="rec-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.stripes-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* Align items to the left side */
  margin-left: 200px; /* Adjust the left margin as needed */
}

.rec-1 {
  height: 0;
  width: 72.5%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px; /* change left depend on your desire */
  top: 30px; /* change top depend on your desire */
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; /* Set initial border to transparent */
  animation: expandHeight 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes expandHeight {
  0% {
    height: 0; /* Start with 0 height */
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%; /* Expand to 100% height */
  }
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-color: #1DCDFE;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-color: #11FFC4;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-color: #21D0B2;
}

.rec-1:nth-of-type(4) {
  border-color: #2F455C;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="stripes-1">
  <span class="rec-1"></span>
  <span class="rec-1"></span>
  <span class="rec-1"></span>
  <span class="rec-1"></span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

1- i set align-items: flex-start on the .stripes-1 container to align the lines to the left side.

2- The height property of .rec-1 is initially set to 0, and we animate it to 100% using the expandHeight animation.

3- i removed the unnecessary transform and animation properties that were causing the rotation and unwanted effects.
4- The border color is set for each nth-of-type element using the border-color property instead of border-bottom, and the border-bottom color is set to transparent initially.

With these modifications, the lines will grow vertically from their initial angle of 40 degrees without any rotation. Feel free to adjust the margins and other properties to fit your animation requirements.

Comment: I wonder... Who votes for such answers? You testing  code, reproduced it? Where is the 40 degree rotate, where is the animation? What are you even animating?! Is this another response from ChatGPT? I'm not talking about `height` animation performance and content jumps, because you animated blocks have `position: relative;`. Appallingly 

Comment: @imhvost your claiming capacity is very high did you think every code is from Ai,  is answer is useful to someone you think can be useful to you too,  their comments in code you can't expand depend on your needs?  Or you need someone to finish everything for you?

Comment: It's just that your answer doesn't work even in the code snippet you provided. No animation...